# GTM data not correctly populating my reports in GA4

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, report, google-tag-manager

So I just recently set up GTM and have been setting up my GA4 to display the data. I've noticed that my e-commerce parameters (currency, item_name, etc.) haven't been showing up as dimensions in my reports. As you can see in the example of item_list_name below, some of my categories are being populated, but a vast majority show up as "(not set)". This is my item_list_name report under the Monetization overview as example:

[item_list_name of purchased items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeFhC.png)

While browsing through tutorials, I've see that this happens when GTM isn't set up properly so it isn't able to pull the data correctly (or at all). When reading Google documentation, I see that to populate these dimensions, you need to set the item-level parameter inside of an e-commerce event (see below).

[Google documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H51k6.png)

I understand what this means, so instead of listing every value I'm looking for individually (creating a data layer variable for each parameter such as: eventModel.item.item_list_name, eventModel.item.item_name, etc.), I created a custom JavaScript code to pull all the values and return them as an array:

```
​function() {
    var items = {{Data Layer - eventModel Items}};
    if (items && Array.isArray(items)) {
        var itemDetails = items.map(function(item) {
            return {
                item_id: item.item_id || 'undefined',
                item_list_name: item.item_list_name || 'undefined',
                item_name: item.item_name || 'undefined',
                item_variant: item.item_variant || 'undefined',
                item_brand: item.item_brand || 'undefined',
                item_category: item.item_category || 'undefined',
                item_category2: item.item_category2 || 'undefined',
                quantity: item.quantity || 'undefined',
                price: item.price || 0,
                currency: item.currency || 'undefined',
                coupon: item.coupon || 'undefined'
            };
        });
        
        return itemDetails;
    }
    return [];
}
```

This data populates my GTM variables correctly, as I can see each item in a given list and all the data that entails ([GTM Preview mode Variables tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxPBv.png)), but it seems like it isn't populating my GA4 correctly​ as I'm still getting "(not set)/(direct)/etc." in multiple reports, and I can't see data that I know exists based on recent orders I've received. Do I need to go through the brute work of putting each line of data as an individual parameter for each event, or would using the above code as an "ItemDetails" parameter work, and I just implemented it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You are a little confused. To use eCommerce event parameters, you can create a DataLayer. If we are talking about the view_item_list e-commerce event, then it needs three required parameters https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtag#view_item_list.
And yes, when you create a tag for this event, all these three parameters must be passed as event params.
item_list_name: item.item_list_name || 'undefined' - a possible source of undefined names lies here. If you don't extract the list name, it is replaced with an ambiguity. I advise you to look at the event parameters in the debugging mode.